# Access web.config from plain html template file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a site which loads html dynamically by making an ajax request to pull a .html page. Its just a plain html page used as a starting point before javascript turns it into something else. In this file I have a link to an external url. I would like to be able to put that url inside my web config.

What would be the suggested method to achieve this?

My Thoughts:

Ditch the html file all together and just build the template completely via javascript then just have the url in a javascript config file (which i already have).

Turn this html page into a cs.html page

--

If there's a way to keep my current framework that would be nice for the time being. Being able to set this/these values in a config file would make deployments much easier.

Comment: Make a controller + action that returns the "simple" view and that way you can access the web.config from the controller or the view.

Comment: Based on your given criteria and situation, why do you need the URL in a config file at all?  Why not just put it in the html file itself or is it used elsewhere?

Comment: During deployments between test and production this url changes. being in an isolated file just makes the deployment harder to do properly as its easy to forget to change